# NuGet exited with code -1 — Build failing as a result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, build, nuget, dotless

I have installed dotless via Package Manager in VS2012 in to an existing mixed C# solution (Class libraries and MVC2 apps), however now when I build it (F5) I get the following two errors:

> The command ""C:\@GitRepos\EBS\SolutionFiles\.nuget\nuget.exe" install
>   "C:\@GitRepos\EBS\\packages.config" -source "" -o
>   "C:\@GitRepos\EBS\SolutionFiles\packages"" exited with code -1.

and

> The system cannot find the path specified.

After adding dotless to the solution a ".nuget" folder with "NuGet.exe and "NuGet.targets" has been added.

I have also tried adding dotless to a new MVC2 project and other than having to add a mime type to the web.config it all works well. There isn't however a ".nuget" folder.

I also noticed that the same happens if I create a new NServiceBus solution (after installing it). The paths in the message change but the error is the same.

If I take

> "C:\@GitRepos\EBS\SolutionFiles\.nuget\nuget.exe" install
>   "C:\@GitRepos\EBS\\packages.config" -source "" -o
>   "C:\@GitRepos\EBS\SolutionFiles\packages"

and run it via a command prompt then I get:

> All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.

Comment: So after giving up on this and then a few days later looking in to it again, I found the answer.

I came across http://david-martos.blogspot.co.uk/. After opening my command prompt and finding it also said "The system cannot find the path specified" I went looking in the registry. I found in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" that there was an AutoRun key for "c:\ansi140\x64\ansicon.exe -p ". After deleting this and trying one of my NserviceBus solutions again I found it built fine.

I hope this helps others.

Comment: You should post this one as answer, it helps me and I would never guess to look this way by myself.

Answer (score 29):

So after giving up on this and then a few days later looking in to it again, I found the answer. I came across david-martos.blogspot.co.uk. After opening my command prompt and finding it also said `"The system cannot find the path specified"` I went looking in the registry. I found in `"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"` that there was an AutoRun key for `"c:\ansi140\x64\ansicon.exe -p "`. After deleting this and trying one of my NserviceBus solutions again I found it built fine. I hope this helps others.

Here is a direct link to [David Martos post](http://david-martos.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/como-que-system-cannot-find-path.html).

Comment: I'm using conemu/cmdr console emulator and it hijacked the same registry key causing me issues.

Comment: Key bit for me that was different from the blog and pointed out above was the location of the reg key "HKEY_CURRENT_USER", the blog points you to local machine so look in both places depending on your setup.

Comment: I deleted ansicon because cmder was complaining and I didn't think I needed it. After two days of trying to figure this out I found this page. Thank you.....

Comment: Yes, i have an ansicon, becouse i am installed it. But i have the same problem in VS. I deleted key AutoRun, but this not works for me =(

Comment: YEAH!=) Just deleting the folder .nuget (in the solution folder) and then running the application do the trick for me! Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Mine was in this path: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Command Processor\"

Answer (score 8):

This was also likely a nuget package restore consent that you had to set. http://blog.nuget.org/20120518/package-restore-and-consent.html

For anyone who wants to permanently have the consent accepted, take a look at installing http://nuget.org/packages/NuGetEnablePackageRestore - it will be accepted on all machines automatically.

Answer (score 5):

Just execute the command below from NuGet Package Manager Console. It worked for me:

```
PM> Install-Package NuGetEnablePackageRestore
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by opening up the Package Manager Console and clicking on the "Restore" button on the warning that popped up.  Here's a pick of what it looked like.  This is similar to the other solutions, but from a different angle.

[image]

Comment: I also had NuGet inexplicably failing. I opened "Manage NuGet packages" for a random project in the solution, clicked on the "Restore" button in the popup and then everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error:

> "The command "" exited with code -1." and "The system cannot find the path specified."

I tested all the possible solutions I found and nothing worked, at the end what I did was take the NuGet.exe from another project and replace it in the project inside the .nuget folder that was generating the error and is working now.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had accidentally deleted the NuGet.Config file from the root of my project directory. Fortunately, I could restore it with source control.

Here's the content of my file if anyone have done the same mistake as me and doesn't have a backup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositorypath" value="NuGet Packages" />
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="NuGet Packages" />
  </config>  
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>  
</configuration>
```